# Laravel: is function __construct required if passing a parameter?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a bunch of functions related to image processing so I made an `ImageProcessing.php` class for my controller to reference.  I put the code below -- in my `ImageProcessing` class, do I need a construct function and if so, what would I need to put in since I am passing in the data I need already?  I am new to Laravel from doing Kotlin for years so I'm still learning the ins and outs.

**Controller**

```
public function processSmallImages(Request $request)
{
    $imageId = $request->input('image_id');
    $image = Image::where('id', '=', $imageId)->first();

    return (new ImageProcessing)->processSmall($image->id);
}
```

**ImageProcessing.php**

```
use App\Models\Image;

class Image 

    public function processSmall($imageId)
    {
        $image = Image::find($imageId);
         //// do Image stuff

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you do not need to have a constructor. As you said you already have the data you wanted, so just pass the data to the method is ok. However, in the future, if something (data) is needed to boot up your class only then you will need to have a constructor and pass the data into the constructor.